# How to do client certificate verification (mTLS) in Starlette/FastAPI

Tags: fastapi, asgi, starlette, mtls

I’m considering using FastAPI framework for implementing rather simple API, but it needs to support mTLS. AFAIK FastAPI is based on Starlette. Is it possible to check client certificate in Starlette?

Comment: Everything is possible, but wouldn't it be easier to handle SSL on a webserver (nginx, apache etc) and forward the meta headers to your upstream application?

Comment: @HeddevanderHeide Probably it would be, but in my case, client identification shall be done base on the certificate and the certificates to be registered through the same API, so nginx-base setup could be quite complex. Currently considering different options.

Actually I came across with this https://www.ajg.id.au/2018/01/01/mutual-tls-with-python-flask-and-werkzeug/ WSGI-based solution and thought similar could be done with ASGI/Starlette. Unfortunatelly my experience in the topic is not enough, so I was looking for some hints from people familiar with the topic.

Comment: I wish @tomchristie could help with this

Comment: Would you be so kind as so give an example of how this was accomplished or point me somewhere?  I'm struggling to find useful documentation on this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, according to [Starlette documentation](https://www.starlette.io/), you may use a **HTTPSRedirectMiddleware** to force use of https, but **no certificate verification is natively implemented** in [Starlette](https://www.starlette.io/).

You may re-implement a cert verification yourself but it will be very dirty ... in my opinion the best is to hanlde the certicate verification directly on the webserver or the middleware.

You may use [uwsgi](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HTTPS.html) to [treat client certificate authentification](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HTTPS.html#client-certificate-authentication) or (re-)implement your api using [Flask](https://github.com/pallets/flask) + [Gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) which will allow you to do client certificate verification. (e.g [here](https://tech-habit.info/posts/https-cert-based-auth-with-flask-and-gunicorn/))

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We ended up checking client certificates with Gunicorn (API itself is being implemented with FastAPI and running with uvicorn).